# Cannot Connect to XenServer from XenCenter

Tags: xen, xenserver

Setup;
 - XenCenter (running on a Windows PC)
 - XenServer (installed via APT on Ubuntu 18.04 using the command, `sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-4.9-amd64`

I can SSH into the server fine.

Whenever I click on 'Add New Server' in XenCenter I get the error message;

`Unable to connect to server '192.168.0.123'. The connection was refused. Check that XenServer is configured correctly on '192.168.0.123' and try again`

It was my understanding that the 'configuration' of the XenServer was done via XenCenter once it was installed?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check first the port 443 if allowed. https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX101810#XenServer

Then run the 'xe-toolstack-restart' command and try the XenCenter again.